# How To Add Code From Another Website To Yours?

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have some code here:

```
<div class="social-icons desktop">
<div class="icons-container">
<p>Let's be friends!</p>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/iloveshowpo" target="_blank"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/Facebook.png" alt="" /></a><a     href="https://www.instagram.com/showpo" target="_blank"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/Instgram.png" alt="" /></a><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/showponytv" target="_blank"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/Youtube.png" alt="" /></a><a href="https://www.pinterest.com/iloveshowpo" target="_blank"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/Pinterest.png" alt="" /></a><a href="http://www.showpo.com/snapchat-thelazyceo" target="_blank"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/snapchat.png" alt="" /></a></div>
```

It's near the very bottom of the Showpo website. I want to add this to my own site replaced with links to my own social media accounts, but how do I add this code to my website's html? I tried copying it and it didn't work. Not very experienced in any coding, so all help would be appreciated. I just can't seem to get this to work for me. The code origin website is: http://www.iloveshowpo.com/

Answer (score 2):

As already said, you cannot do it. However, `<iframe>`s may be sometimes useful - it let you to have a "webpage inside an another webpage".

It's not what you want, but it's a bit near.

Answer (score 1):

You just cannot add the HTML to your own website. You will need to add the pictures and CSS that affects those element to your website's directory.

Just as a side note I would suggest that you not take code from other people's website you can get messed up in copyright and other legal issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Wowsk. I can do the pictures, but as far as the CSS I'm not sure what it would be, &  where would I put the CSS? In the html? I know HTML and CSS are different, but where do you put CSS?

Comment: You have two options:

Comment: 1. Look through the CSS files for the CSS that applies to the elements you are dealing with.

Comment: 2. Inspect element on what you want to copy and copy the CSS that appears on the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the css codes and copy the relevant to your css page. At first you need to download the images and change the link of image to your directory